# Create table with Cyclic Dependency in sequelize,

Tags: mysql, node.js, spring, spring-boot, sequelize.js

I have created two tables employee and department.
An **`employee`** has the following attribute:

```
1. id
2. Name
3. Department(fk, refer to department id )
```

**`Department`**:

```
1. id
2. HeadOfDepartment(fk, refer to employee id)
```

As it is pretty clear from above statement, cyclic dependency exists between this two table.

When I run the statement to create this two table using sequelize, it throws "**`cyclic dependency error`**", And as suggested by stack overflow, I introduced an attribute called "constraint" and set it to false. and when I query the structure of above table, there was no constraint which means there was no association.  Is there any route, where I can create a table with cyclic dependency without introducing the third table and without using "Alter " statement.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this (at least with the limited capabilities of MySQL) to allow NULL values in both FK columns.

Comment: Hi @Bhusan,  I set the constraints to false and "allowNull" to true. but no effect

Comment: @Dila are you using hibernate?

Comment: on java side Hibernate. yupp. For node i am using sequelize

Comment: so are you facing this issue with hibernate or node(sequelize)?